# Why does this crash browser tab?

Tags: javascript

Its not like I couldn't do it otherwise, but I'm just curious: Why does this code crashes the browser tab?

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var a = document.createElement("A");
    a.innerHTML = "[?]";
    a.href = links[i].href; //this is the evil line
    a.onclick = function () {
        return false;
    };
    links[i].parentNode.appendChild(a);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the `NodeList` (I think they call it an `HTMLCollection` now) you get back from `getElementsByTagName` is **live**. So when you add a new `a` to the document, the browser adds it to the list you're looping through. Since you add another one each time you loop, you'll never reach the end of the loop.

If you want a disconnected array or collection instead, you can do:

```
var collection = document.querySelectorAll("a");
```

or

```
var array = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a"));
```

`querySelectorAll` supports the full range of CSS selectors. It's supported by all modern browsers, and also IE8. But it may be slower than cloning the `getElementsByTagName` `NodeList` (not that that usually matters).

Answer (score 3):

[`Element.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) returns a **live** [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), meaning each time you add a new link element to the page, the length of links increases, leading to an infinite loop.